# Swift: JSON Decode fails in some cases

Tags: json, swift

I have this struct

```
struct ProductInfo: Codable {
    
    var code: String
    var product_name: String?
    var status: Int
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case code
        case product
        case status
        
        enum ProductCodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
            case product_name
        }
    }
    
    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        
        let rootContainer = try! decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        let productContainer = try! rootContainer.nestedContainer(keyedBy: CodingKeys.ProductCodingKeys.self, forKey: .product)
        
        product_name = try! productContainer.decode(String.self, forKey: .product_name)
        
        
        code = try! rootContainer.decode(String.self, forKey: .code)
        status = try! rootContainer.decode(Int.self, forKey: .status)
        
        
    }
    
    func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        var rootContainer = encoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        var productContainer = rootContainer.nestedContainer(keyedBy: CodingKeys.ProductCodingKeys.self, forKey: .product)
        
        try rootContainer.encode(code, forKey: .code)
        try rootContainer.encode(status, forKey: .status)
        try productContainer.encode(product_name, forKey: .product_name)
    }
}
```

Problem is that is the product is not found on the DB, the CodingKey "product" will not exist, only code and status are available.

That means, this line

```
let productContainer = try! rootContainer.nestedContainer(keyedBy: CodingKeys.ProductCodingKeys.self, forKey: .product)
```

Will fail because the key is not found in the JSON Response.
My idea was to check the status value (which I have in the Response) but it seems not working

Thanks

Comment: Unrelated but: Why use `try!` except for wanting your app to crash?

Comment: You are right, of course. But it crashes even without ```try!```

Comment: Can you show the two cases of your JSON? One with the "product", and one without the product?

Comment: Why do you need a separate container to encode the `product_name` property?

Comment: Here we are: ```{"code":"4007843212122","status":0,"status_verbose":"product not found"}``` when product is not present and here when is present ```{
   "code":"8001620004159",
   "product":{
      "_id":"8001620004159",
      "product_name":"The San Benedetto",
   },
   "status":1,
   "status_verbose":"product found"
}```

Comment: @JoakimDanielson well I could be wrong, but I am not using a new container, I am parsing the container to get the product_name

Comment: Never mind, I thought the problem was when encoding and not decoding.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`contains(_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/keyeddecodingcontainer/2893337-contains):

```
if rootContainer.contains(.product) {
    let productContainer = try rootContainer.nestedContainer(keyedBy: CodingKeys.ProductCodingKeys.self, forKey: .product)
    product_name = try productContainer.decode(String.self, forKey: .product_name)
}
```

To test it:

```
let jsonStr = """
[
  {
    "code": "8001620004159",
    "product": { "_id": "8001620004159", "product_name": "The San Benedetto" },
    "status": 1,
    "status_verbose": "product found"
  },
  {
    "code": "4007843212122",
    "status": 0,
    "status_verbose": "product not found"
  }
]
"""
let jsonData = Data(jsonStr.utf8)


do {
    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
    let items = try decoder.decode([ProductInfo].self, from: jsonData)
    print(items)
} catch {
    print("Error: \(error)")
}
```

Side note:
I'd avoid `try!` and replace them with `try` since the method `throws` already.